# PHP not executed when in subdirecory with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

When going on `example.com`, `example.com/foo/` or `example.com/foo/bar/`, PHP was working great. Then I tried to modify Nginx conf to have `foo.example.com` pointing on `example.com/foo/` (the DNS is already configured). It works, but now when I access to `foo.example.com/bar/`, I can download `foo/bar/index.php` instead of executing it.

Here is the Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    *.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/;


    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    foo.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/foo/;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   web_fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I know there are plenty of similar threads, but none of those I read worked.

Comment: The first server declaration catches the request and since there is no php location block, nginx just outputs the file. Add a php location block and try again.

Comment: Great! Make it an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first server declaration catches the request and since you don't have a PHP location block in this server declaration, Nginx just outputs the file. You need to add a PHP location block to the first server declaration.